# Background image of absolute div cuts off on scroll

Tags: html, css

I know there are other posts out there like this one, but I can't seem to find an exact answer... so...

I would like to create a jquery slideshow where background images fade in over each other, so instead of putting a background image in the body tag, I'm creating a div which fills the entire screen and placing other elements, like a menu, over the top. But when I make the viewport smaller than the height of the menu and scroll down, I get a background coloured block moving up over my image. I've tried everything I can think of to fix this, but I'm totally stuck.

Here is a simplified version. The red block is where the image will be, the black is the background colour and the menu is overlaid in grey. CSS:

```
body, html {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #000000;
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 1em;
    line-height: 1em;
    color: #9E9E9E;
    position: relative;
}
body {
    text-align: center;
}
* {padding: 0px; margin: 0px}
#wrap {
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    background-color: #900;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1000;
}
#menu_wrap {
    width: 390px;
    min-height: 100%;
    background-color: #656262;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 9999;
    background: rgb(101, 98, 98);
    background: rgba(101, 98, 98, 0.9);
    -ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=90)";
    filter: alpha(opacity=90);
}
#menu_wrap #menu_content {
    padding: 40px;
    height: 500px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="wrap"></div>

<div id="menu_wrap">
    <div id="menu_content">Menu content goes here - it could be any height.</div>Menu extends to here.
</div>
```

Any help would be hugely appreciated. It might be that I've just missed something really simple, but I feel like I'm banging my head up against a brick wall. Thanks.

Comment: Would an alternative be to use position: fixed on the #wrap ?

Comment: That's done it! I knew it would be something simple - what a star. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a jsfiddle link which I think does what you want it to do.

http://jsfiddle.net/Alfalfamale/dCgRW/1/

The problem with your setup is that the wrap div min height (100%) will always be the height of it's parent at 100%, which is the body, which is always only the viewport size.

To fix this I moved the menu inside wrap and made it float instead of absolutely positioned. This way the menu stays 'in-flow' of the document and takes up space in `#wrap`. Secondly we add `overflow: hidden` to the wrap, essentially clearing the left menu.

I may have left in some styles which aren't essential in a float setup, I'm sure you can pick those out yourself :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer - that was really helpful, but I think sphair has nailed it for me.